# How can I add multiple functions to one file?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a mash Up of sorts... I want the functions to be in one file but when I add my Ajax functions (half way down ) nothing displays.

Also I want to display them with jQuery, and the top function(Google maps with marker and info) all works a treat until I add the bottom functions.

Should I add them in the (function () {} ) like Google has and what is the (); on the end of the googlemap function?

and when I call my functions in my code how will I call the ajax for the preview as the window.onload has been called in the Google one.

I know that I can use the $.ready function(){} but do I just put the function names in the .ready function {  }

I am unsure how to add all the functions in one file and make them work. Basically

this is the code:

```
(function() {

        //define global variables
        var map, geocoder, marker, infowindow;

        window.onload = function() {

            //creating the map
            var options = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.383, -1.483),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

            //code for catching the form submit event goes here
            //Getting the reference to the HTML form
            var form = document.getElementById('addressForm');

            //Catching the forms submit event
            form.onsubmit = function () {

                //getting the address from the text input
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

                //Making the geocode call
                getAddress(address);

                //Preventing the form from doing a page submit
                return false;
                }
            }

            //Function Stub
            function getAddress(address) {

                //Check to see if we already have a geocode object.
                //If not we create one
                if(!geocoder) {
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                }

                //Creating the geoCoderRequest Object   
                var geocoderRequest = {
                    address: address
                }

                //Making the geocode request
                geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) {

                    //Check if status is ok beofre proceeding
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){

                        //Center the map on the returned location
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                        //Check to see if already a Marker there
                        if (!marker){
                            //Create a new marker and add it to the map
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map    
                                });
                            }
                        //Setting position of the Marker to returned location
                        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);

                            //Check to see if we've already an info window
                            if(!infowindow) {
                                //Creating a new info window
                                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                }
                            //Creating the content of the info window to the Address
                            //and the returned position
                            var content = '<strong>' + results[0].formatted_address + '</strong><br />';
                            content += 'Lat: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + '<br />';
                            content += 'Lng: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                            //Adding the content to the info window
                            infowindow.setContent(content);

                            //Opening the infoWindow
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);

                        }

                });
            }

            })();


    // beginning of new function
            var xhr = false;
            var xPos, yPos;

            function prev(){
                    var link = document.getElementByTagName("a").onmouseover = showPreview;
                }

        function showPreview(evt) {
            if (evt) {
                var url = evt.target;
            }
            else{
                evt = window.event;
                var url = evt.srcElement;
            }
            xPos = evt.clientX;
            yPos = evt.clientY;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    try {
                        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) { }
                }
            }

            if (xhr) {
                xhr.onreadystatechange = showContents;
                xhr.open("GET", url, true);
                xhr.send(null);
            }
            else {
                alert("Sorry, but I couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest");
            }
            return false;
        }

            function showContents() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        var outMsg = xhr.responseText;
                    }
                    else {
                        var outMsg = "There was a problem with the request " + xhr.status;
                        }
                        var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
                        preview.innerHTML = outMsg;
                        preview.style.top = parseInt(yPos)+2 + "px";
                        preview.style.left = parseInt(xPos)+2 + "px";
                        preview.style.visibility = "visible";

                        preview.onmouseout = function(){
                            document.getElementById('preview').style.visibility = "hidden";
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on why you're adding functions. but here is a simple formula. If you want you're functions to be called on document ready only and want them to be called once when the document is loaded. Then you add them as "anonymous functions"

EXAMPLE:

```js
$(function () {
    //you code
    ...............
    // you can call your named functions also here. 
    //like
    somefunction();
});
```

But if you expect them to be called later on as well, when the document has already been loaded. Then add the "named functions"

EXAMPLE:

```js
function somename()
{
    ............
}
```

In both cases you can have them in one file and regarding the `();` at the end of the function, it is a way of calling anonymous functions immediately in JavaScript, like `document.ready` in jQuery.